# Convert my Bootstrap site to a Drupal theme

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal, drupal-8

I made a website in Bootstrap with some Javascript and PHP. I have a client where I build this website for, who wants his website in Drupal, so he can change the text and such.

But how do I do this? I followed many tutorials but none of them worked. I have a large file with all the code but there is private information in the code so I'm not posting it on here. If you need it just say so.

If you can provide me with a decent tutorial of Drupal 8 with bootstrap where I can implement my website of something? that would be amazing!

Comment: Drupal 8 is a powerful and complex CMS. You can't learn it in week or two, just to meet some deadline. If it's that urgent my advice is to find some experienced D8 developer to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Tutorial for D8 theming:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming

Themes in D8 are using twig - so another thing to learn:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

If you want to give your client full, ready to use website, then you need to know, how to:

- write module,
- manage drupal website,
- create/manage content types,
- using views,

and many more. Its possible IMO, but i think it will be very hard if you dont know Drupal at all. Install drupal, learn, learn and learn. Try to create simple theme first